# How do you create XOR relationship in GenMyModel?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a task where I am supposed to create a UML class diagram. Let me paraphrase:

> There are two types of storage units (A and B). An item can only be placed in a storage unit of type A or B.

The book I'm using described the use of XOR relationship, as shown bellow on [this site](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html):

[image: UML XOR relationship]

i.e. for my example, an item can only be associated with storage unit of type A or B.
I quite like the tool [GenMyModel](https://app.genmymodel.com/). Is there way to represent this in that tool? I've searched like mad and can't find anything.

Cheers,
Delectable Tea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenMyModel is a quite nice tool, but also quite limited in its UML support. The "relation" you are demanding here is called a *constraint*. Constraints are a quite informally handled and not really commonly used topic in UML. So there plenty of tools that have no proper support of it. Then you can draw - thought but not model - constraints, i.e., just use other model elements or free forms to get something that looks like this.

Comment: Does that mean, that the relationship of constraints can't be modelled in a way that let's you generate a class structure in actual code like GenMyModel does?

Comment: I am not really sure if I get your question right. But there are generators that can handle some specific constraints, mostly some which they define on their own. When you mean generating manually, then it is independent of the tool und just up the human mind if you can generator code out of it. In general it is better to use OCL as constraint langauge. It gives you a clear syntax and thorough semantics and a clear context to constraints to apply in your model.